# Bing scraper navigation

Tags: excel, vba

My code all of a sudden does not seem to want to work and I can not work out why. Most of it is fine, there are only two issue with it now and I can not work them out. I was trying to improve it and may have moved someting around and can not work out what I have done. I need a some one to look at this for me please. I have highlighted the issue in the code that are the problem. The bulk of this is fine and I am happy with it.

1. It no longer clicks on the next page in Bing
2. It Loops minus 2, so if I put in 10 loops then it does 8. Maybe I have put the loop counter in the wrong place, hence it could be showing wrong results

Its not the best code in the world, but it was something I wrote and it worked fine up until a few weeks back. I have been trying to fix it but can not work it out so decided to post.

**What I have done so Far.**

1. I tried to google the answer
2. I tried to fix it myself. I managed to fix other smaller bugs but can't fix navigation
3. I Checked the  BING CLASS for next page, looks the same to me. I have always used the one in yellow

[image]

```
Private Sub BingScraper()
'''Bing URL SCRAPER
Dim ie As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Dim nextPageElements As Object
Dim li As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim url As String
Dim pageNumber As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim myCounter As Long

'''Takes seach from Sheet10 to google
    url = "https://www.Bing.com/search?q=" & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G17").Value & Range("H17").Value, " ", "+")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate url
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End With

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document

'''Searches URLS and places them in Sheet called Sheet2  ROW 2 Column A
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    pageNumber = 2
    'i = 2
    i = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1
Do

    For Each li In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("li")
   ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        If li.getAttribute("class") = "b_algo" Then
            Set link = li.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    
    Next li

'#####################################################################################
'################################# ISSUE STARTS FROM HERE ############################
    
'''Searches Number of Pages entered in Sheet10 i17
    If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("I17").Value, " ", "+") Then Exit Do
        On Error Resume Next

     '#################### THIS IS THE CLASS FOR BING NEXT PAGE ################
        Set nextPageElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("sb_pagN sb_pagN_bp b_widePag sb_bp")(0)      
    If nextPageElements Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                
'''Scrolls Down the Browser
    ie.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 99999
'''Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet10
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("J17").Value))
        
  '######################## NO LONGER GOING TO NEXT PAGE ######################
    nextPageElement.Click 'next web page
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
'''Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet10
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("K17").Value))
        Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
''' Delete duplicates
    Sheet2.Columns("A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes

     pageNumber = pageNumber + 1

'######################### LOOP COUNTER ######################
myCounter = myCounter + 1
Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G6").Value = myCounter

    Loop
''' Delete Row If Blank
    Sheet2.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With

'################################# ISSUE END HERE ############################
'#############################################################################

If Sheet10.Range("I17") = 0 Then
    Complete.Show
        Termination.Hide
 
ElseIf Sheet10.Range("I17") > 0 Then
   Complete.Show
End If

ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
    Set nextPageElements = Nothing
    Set li = Nothing
    Set link = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `nextPageElements` always point to the item with index 0. Thus, it always stay on the first page. You need an index variable for it.  Also, the `Replace()` return a string. I am not sure how you want it to compare with `pageNumber ` (cannot give further comment as I don't know the content of `I17` in Sheet 10.

Comment: Oliver Leung - Thanks for the reply, I have worked out the navigation issue, I was using the work `Elements` when it should have been `Element` WITHOUT the "s". this has allwed the navigation. All though it only shows going to page 2, if pull the results of for the rest of the pages, a bit strange, but still works. The LOOPS are still 2 short is my counter in the wrong place? Please advise

Comment: **Ignore my above post,** Having looked at my original code I realised that all I need to do was add and "s" here `nextPageElement.Click 'next web page` so it read as `nextPageElements.Click 'next web page`. I have changed it all back to **Elements** with the **"s"** as for some reason the browser would **NOT** close when I changed it to **"Element"**. LOOP counter is still an issue, if anyone can help then that would be super.

Comment: I have fixed the Loop counter, it was not counting the first time the code was run or the last, so I moved the position of the counter and it records both incidents 1st and last loop.

Comment: Glad that you find the solution.